# To print prime numbers between m and n when m and n are quite large in the range 10^10 using sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: c++, algorithm

My code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define s 100001
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long arr[s],i,j,t,m,n;
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    arr[i] = 1;

 arr[0] = 0;
 arr[1] = 0;

 for(i=2;i<sqrt(s);i++)
 {
     if(arr[i] == 1)
     {
         for(j=2;i*j<s;j++)
            arr[i*j] = 0;
     }
 }




 cin >> t;
 while(t--)
 {
     cin >> m >> n;
     if(n<s)
     {
     for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
     {
         if(arr[i] == 1)
            cout << i << endl;
     }
     }
 }

return 0;
}
```

This code is showing run time error for larger input of m and n as the array size is just 10^5 long. When I was making the array of 10^10 there was a compilation error and it is showing this much bigger array is not possible.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I expect you got a stack overflow! Remember the default stack is a few MB on windows or linux.

Comment: On a stylistic note, I advise that you not use single-letter variables if you plan on others viewing this code. Use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Why is it that these "online judge" questions **never** just show us the input that doesn't work?  Instead we get a bunch of `cin` statements, where the first is the "number of test cases"?  We don't care about the number of test cases -- just hard-code the input that fails into the program and post that program, not the actual program you submitted.  Rant off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Sieve Of Eratosthenes, compute all primes from 0 to 10^5. This is based on the fact that all composite numbers must have at least 1 prime factor less than or equal to its square root.

Once all of the primes have been computed, store all the primes (I suggest using a vector). Then when looping through the numbers from `n` to`m`, use the saved primes to test for primality.

The following sieve function should do the job:

```
bitset<100005> bs;
vector<long long> primes;
void sieve(){
    bs.set();
    bs[0] = bs[1] = 0;
    for (long long i = 2; i <= 100000; ++i){
        if (bs[i]){
            primes.push_back(i);
            for (long long j = i*i; j <= 100000; j += i) bs[j] = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use an array of long long, a bitset will do. Using a global variable instead of a local one can solve the runtime error.

```
bitset<s> arr;
```

However, if you're going to use sieve of eratosthenes for numbers that large, it might take a long while to get the right answer, so it will get TLE on online judges.

Comment: Please elaborate, the solution . I am just beginner.

Answer (score 0):

First do not use long long but bitset or char(portable also in C, recommended language for this kind of programs). It just need to store a boolean flag. The number hold by the slot is given by start_value+index.
Second the for-loop, should move with step current_prime. i+=2, i+=3, i+=5 and so on.
The pseudo code will be:

```
first_prime_array="compute the prime number until sqrt(n)"
while(first_prime_array contains prime number)
{
   start=seek first position in main_array divisible by  current_prime
   for (i=start;i<n;i+=current_prime)
       main_array[i]=1;

}
print all the values ==0 hold in main_array as m+index;
```